# How to leave empty cell when for loop does not work?

Tags: python, for-loop, error-handling

```
for x in range(50):
    df['New Column'][x] = chi2_contingency([[df['A'][x],df['B'][x]],[df['C'][x],df['D'][x]]])

I want it like this:

Column A    Column B    New Column (result of for loop)
1             2           10           
0             0           ???? (here blank or 1)
5             6           16
```

This function works but since some rows of df['New Column'] have 0 values the final column throws an error. How can we skip those rows (leave blank or return 1) and continue for loop for other rows?

Comment: What do you mean that the for loop "does not work"?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: The for loop is working but not accepting some values. I want to leave the those rows blank (or with an "error value" or 1), so that the for loop can continue running for the next rows.

Comment: Well you can use an `if` condition to make sure that the row is not blank.

Comment: You mean if condition within the for loop? Could you please give an example?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.